# How do I avoid getting assassinated by the Mafia?

Tags: this-is-the-police

When asked to choose between working for the Sand Mafia or not, I chose to work with the Sand Mafia. Then when later asked to choose between Sand and Vargas, I chose to work with Vargas against Sand.

Both of them are requesting for my assistance, and I tried to help them both but I got assassinated later, when I put in more jobs for Vargas. What are the mechanics here? And what should I do to not get assassinated while making sure Vargas wins the gang war?

(I know a character said said something about the game mechanic here, but I forgot about it.)

Comment: @Blazeoffury49er So basically, you are telling me to google it?

Comment: Well yes that’s what most people getting you an answer would do dude

Comment: @Blazeoffury49er https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/here-let-me-google-that-for-you

Comment: Not even that relevant, I literally just left you a comment giving some advice I’m not copy and pasting google for an answer which most people probs would do dude

Comment: @Blazeoffury49er Read the answers in the linked meta post. If I already found the answer through googling it, why would I bother asking a question here in the first place? I specifically asked here because I don't know of and can't find sources of info. Comments akin to "google it", are not constructive and not helpful. If anyone found the answer through google, then they are more than welcome to "copy and paste" it here, provided they name the source.

Comment: Your getting a little over the top about this, also 90% of the questions asked are resolved by a simple google you seem to forget that. I never even told you to just google it I just gave a suggestion for what to search in the comments.

Comment: @Blazeoffury49er When I asked you if you are telling me to google it, you said "yes." Again, if I already found the answer through googling it, why would I bother asking a question here in the first place? Instead of telling people to google it, you should just post the answer and provide the source. That is more helpful than commenting and telling users to google it.

Comment: “Post the answer and provide the source” yes because that’s what the comment section is for. If this was an actual answer I would y’know get your point but it’s not. Also googling what you want now wouldn’t even provide the same results as googling a playthrough which is what I suggested. Also I only said well yes because when I replied to that it was late and to be honest I didn’t care that much.